# Java, parse string to bigdecimal issue

Tags: java, string, parsing, bigdecimal

I try to parse this String into a bigdecimal with comma replaced by a point.

```
String priceStr = "0,04";
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
df.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
BigDecimal price = null;
try {
        price = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(priceStr);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But i get an integer instead of a bigdecimal value(price = 4).
Any idea?

Comment: That's not a number formatted in US locale.

Comment: how can i detect which locale is it from?

Answer (score 4):

`0,04` is not a number formatted in the US locale.

If the value you expect to be parsed from that is `0.04`, you would need to use another locale which does use `,` as a decimal separator, e.g. `Locale.FRANCE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert a non-US local decimal to a US local one you have to do two conversions, i.e.,

```
String priceStr = "0,04";
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
df.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
BigDecimal price = null;
try {
    price = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(priceStr);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(price));
```

> how can i detect which locale is it from?

You simply check if the number `String` contains a `.`:

```
DecimalFormat df = (priceStr.contains(".")) ? 
                      (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US) :
                      (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String priceStr = "0,04";
DecimalFormatSymbols symbol=new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbol.setDecimalSeparator(','); 
String Pattarn="#,##";
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat(Pattarn, symbol);
df.setParseBigDecimal(true);

try {
    BigDecimal price = (BigDecimal) df.parse(priceStr);
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```